# python async - efficiency of sleeping multiple coroutines

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

**Context**: I am making a discord bot, and the mute command comes with a duration specifier for when the user should be unmuted again (this is being done via assigning a role to the user that removes their ability to send messages).

**Idea 1**: I could make a loop that checks every, say, 30 seconds and looks through to see which mutes have expired and cancel them.

**Idea 2**: Each time a mute is processed, I could `await asyncio.sleep(however long)` and then cancel it.

I would like to ask - which is more idiomatic, and also more importantly, which is more efficient? The first one has the advantage that it only has one coroutine running whereas the last one spawns a new one for each individual case (I don't really know how many that might be, but let's say around 10 concurrent cases maximum). However, the last one is easier for me to implement and feels like a more direct solution, on top of making the unmute happen exactly on time instead of on a timed loop.

There is one idea to make a loop that awaits until the next task and then when it processes that, queue up the next one, but then you can't insert tasks at the front of the queue.

**TL;DR** - if I need to schedule multiple events, do I run a loop to constantly check the scheduler, or do I open a coroutine for each and just `await asyncio.sleep(however long)` each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second idea seems the most accurate and straightforward as you can simply use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) to run an unmute coroutine after a certain amount of time. By using `asyncio.create_task`, you do not need to `return` or `yield` back the unmute coroutine to be `gather`ed later or submit it to be checked by a loop at an established interval, for `await`ing the returned response from `asyncio.create_task` will run the task in the background:

```
import asyncio
async def unmute(delay, user_id):
  await asyncio.sleep(delay)
  #run unmute process

async def mute(user_id):
  #your mute function
  mute_for = await do_mute(user_id) #some mute function
  u = asyncio.create_task(unmute(mute_for, user_id))
  await u #submitting the task to be run in the background
```